# Filters for annotate in Django

Tags: django

How can I use Annotate to count only certain conditions?

```
class User(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    

class Tweet(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", related_name="tweet")
    favorite = models.IntegerField(default=0)


# I only want to count tweets with 100 or more favorites.
users = User.objects.annotate(tweet_count=Count("tweet"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add filter option in Count()

give this a try

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

users = User.objects.annotate(
    tweet_count=Count("tweet", filter=Q(tweet__favorite__gte=100))
)
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation)